# String not completely visible in cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I write a String into my cell with setCellValue(), and I open afterwards the created file in Excel, I only see the first three characters.

After a doubleclick on the cell I see the complete String.

Which setting do I have to change when I write the data in the cells ?

Comment: I don't know if this will work, thus just a comment, but what if you set the cell as the active cell prior to saving it to the disk. `Cell.setAsActiveCell()` should do it, but I don't know if that would get the overflow you're looking for.

Comment: try HSSFSheet.setColumnWidth(int columnIndex, int width)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`autoSizeColumn(int column)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29) method on the right column of your sheet: it is equivalent to doucleclicking.

If you want all your columns to have the same width:

1. autosize all the columns you wrote data in
2. go through each of those columns to get the max width using the [getColumnWidth(int column)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getColumnWidth%28int%29) method
3. resize all the columns to the max width using the [setColumnWidth(int columnIndex, int width)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int,%20int%29) method

Answer (score 2):

If the cell is not wide enough to accomodate the new value fully, then you could use:

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(column);
```

Comment: When I use this,  my column is expanded and I see the whole string, but what I want to archieve is that the columnwidth looks the same ( just as wide as the neighbouring cells) with the text completely readable. In an Excelfile where the whole text is displayed correctly, it looks as if the text is stretched over multiple cells, but when I go through the actual cells I see that the complete text is in one cell. That is what I'm looking for ?

Comment: I edited my answer to add the solution to this problem you have :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Problem was that the neighbouring cells had empty Stringvalues ( "" ) in them.
Looping through these cells and setting the cell values to an null-String did the trick.